# Web sites denying access to a Azure VM

Tags: azure, http-status-code-403, azure-virtual-machine

I have a VM at Azure, when I try to access some web sites I get a Denied Access message. It seems they understand the request is coming from a VM and don't allow access. I tried with Chrome, Chromium thru Python/Selenium and Edge.

Example: www.americanas.com.br

Error Message: 
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.americanas.com.br/" on this server. Reference #18.ac3c2b17.1545339126.29ba0fa7

The issue does not happens all the time, but for more than 50% of the number of accesses.

I have already tried without success:
 - move the location of my VM from US Central/South to Brazil South
 - use a VPN plug-in (Hola)
 - used a fixed IP resource at Azure Portal

Thanks in advance
Ricardo